# noSuchMethodError elementAt while using listView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

when I `print(snapshot.data)` the data is there,.. but when displayed it appears
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MugOt.png)
this is my code

```
  _showActivities() {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: UserController.getActivityByDate(
      {"date": widget.index.toIso8601String(), "id": widget.user}),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data != null){
        print(snapshot.data);
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            var item = snapshot.data[position];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("${item["activity"]["project"]}"),
              subtitle: Text(item["created_at"]),
            );
          });
      }

    } 
      return Text("no data displayed");

  },
);
```

and this is the data I want to display

```
[


{
    "id": 114,
    "id_user": 114,
    "activity": {
      "code": 2003,
      "project": "Sangat Damai Sejahtera",
      "activity": {
        "name": "Laporan Sales Order Trading",
        "id_process_snapshot": 5016
      },
      "code_name": "SaveProcessSnapshot"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-07-12T17:00:13.931592+07:00"
  },
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix the following, then if there are more errors, update your question and I'll try to improve the answer.

snapshot.hasData is a bool it is never null.

Change

```
if (snapshot.hasData != null)
```

to

```
if (snapshot.hasData)
```

If you really want to check for null use the following (but hasData should suffice).

```
if (snapshot.data != null)
```

Then to fix the error you have shown in the image change

```
snapshot.data.elementAt(position);
```

to

```
snapshot.data[position]; //if the object being returned is a list
```

getActivityByDate returns a json so it would be best to create objects from the json. Here is some **pseudo code** to create User and Activity objects from the JSON.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart'; //add json_annotation: ^2.2.0 in your pubspec

@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class User extends Object {
  int id, id_user;
  String created_at;
  Activity activity;

  User({this.id,this.id_user,this.activity,this.created_at});

  User _userFromJson(Map<String, dynamic>json){
    return new User(
      id: json["id"] as int,
      id_user: json["id_user"] as int,
      activity: new Activity()._activityFromJson(json["activity"]),
      created_at: json["created_at"] as String,
    );
  }
}
class Activity extends Object {
  int code, id_process_snapshot;
  String project, name, code_name;

  Activity({this.code,this.name, this.id_process_snapshot,this.project,this.code_name});

  Activity _activityFromJson(Map<String, dynamic>json){
    return new Activity(
      code: json["code"] as int,
      project: json["project"] as String,
      name: json["activity"]["name"] as String,
      id_process_snapshot: json["activity"]["id_process_snapshot"] as int,
      code_name:  json["activity"]["code_name"] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Back to your code pass your json through the _userFromJson() method

```
User user = User()._userFromJson(snapshot.data);
```

Now you will be able to create your listTiles using

```
return ListTile(
              title: Text("${user.project} -${user.activity.code_name;}"),
              subtitle: Text("${user.created_at}"),
            );
```

Remember json is case sensitive, so double check you are spelling the keys correctly.

Comment: I tried to replace it but the error is still the same ??

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with the last change needed. Change elementAt.

Comment: now the error is different, I have updated the image and the question

Comment: Thanks, what object is snapshot.data returned as? You can use the debugger and breakpoint to pause the app once it has retrieved the data but before it throws the exception.

Comment: so sorry, on flutter web doesn't seem to support breakpoints, but when `print ()` the data is there, I'm the problem with how to display json ??

Comment: Updated answer with some pseudo code, If you have any issues creating an object from the code I've shared you can read more here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the values from the database or api try the code below here the function _getAllValues() return all the list to the builder

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
    future: _getAllValues(),
      builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> list){
      if(list.hasData){
        return new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list.data.length,
            itemBuilder:(context, index){
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(list.data[index]),
              );

            });
      }
```

Comment: if I want to display `["activity"] ["project"]` how ??